# React navigation route params

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parameters, frontend, react-navigation

**I'm using react navigation and want to pass params id to my screen RestaurantInfo but when i console log id in that screen it says "undefined"
How to pass params correctly even the followed the documentation they did it in a similar manner**

Param code:-

```
   const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (


            <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1 }} key={item.id} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(
                "RestaurantInfo",
                {
                    id: 1
                }
            )}>
                <Card style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Card.Title >{item.name}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Title>{item.id}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Image
                        source={{ uri: "https://static.toiimg.com/photo/72975551.cms" }}
                        resizeMode="cover" ></Card.Image>

                    {/*  <Text>
                        <Icon
                            name='email' />
                        Email</Text>
                    <Text> */}


                    <Card.Divider></Card.Divider>
                </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        )
    }
```

Screen Code:-

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

export const restaurantInfo = ({ route, navigation }) => {

    console.log(route);
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Restaurant Info</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Output:-

```
Object {
  "key": "restaurantMenu-u_fPFgzRQgEIhM9l1TDtt",
  "name": "restaurantMenu",
  "params": undefined,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem was solved actually i tried passing param from stack navigator to tab navigator hence there was a name mismatch .Alsoi defined the "RestaurantInfo" screen in stack navigator as well so now i can pass paramsstrong text**